# Chainlink VRF - how to check fullfillRandomness result working

Tags: chainlink

I am working on smart contract to generate random cards with some specific rules, I was trying to use Chainlink VRF to generate random number and implemented such contract.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity >=0.7.4;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
import "../utils/Context.sol";
import "../utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "../utils/Address.sol";
import "../NFT/CardNFTAccessControls.sol";
import "../NFT/CardNFT.sol";

/**
 * @notice Factory contract for NFT handling payments on mint
 */
contract NFTFactory is Context, ReentrancyGuard, VRFConsumerBase {
  // using SafeMath for uint256;
  using Address for address payable;

  struct CardInfo {
    uint256 num;
    uint256 kind;
    uint256 value;
    uint256 qty;
  }

  struct NFTInfo {
    uint256 edition;
    uint256 cardInfoId;
  }

  struct RequestNFTConfig {
    uint256 limit;
    bool kind;
    uint256 id;
  }

  event NFTCreated(
    uint256 id,
    uint256 num,
    uint256 kind,
    uint256 edition
  );

  event RandomReturned(
    bytes32 requestId,
    uint256 randomness
  );

  /// @notice chainlink rng request value mapping
  mapping(bytes32 => RequestNFTConfig) private requestIds;

  /// @notice edition number id
  uint256 private editionId;

  /// @notice for switching off factory functionality
  bool public isPaused;

  /// @notice responsible for enforcing mint and admin role
  CardNFTAccessControls accessControls;

  /// @notice NFT contract
  CardNFT cardNFT;

  /// @notice platform  fee recipient address which will accept all fees and mint price
  address payable platformFeeRecipient;

  /// @notice keyhash for chainlink rng generator
  bytes32 internal keyHash;

  /// @notice fee for chainlink rng generator
  uint256 internal rngFee;

  /// @notice rng generator result
  uint256 public randomResult;

  /// @notice deck card information for calculation
  mapping(uint256 => CardInfo) deckInfo;

  /// @notice nft array
  mapping(uint256 => NFTInfo) nfts;

  modifier whenNotPaused() {
    require(!isPaused, "Function is currently paused");
    _;
  }

  constructor(
    CardNFTAccessControls _accessControls,
    CardNFT _cardNFT,
    address payable _platformFeeRecipient
  ) VRFConsumerBase(
    0xa555fC018435bef5A13C6c6870a9d4C11DEC329C,
    0x84b9B910527Ad5C03A9Ca831909E21e236EA7b06
  ) {
    require(address(_accessControls) != address(0), "NFTFactory: Invalid Access Controls");
    require(address(_cardNFT) != address(0), "NFTFactory: Invalid NFT");
    require(_platformFeeRecipient != address(0), "NFTFactory: Invalid platform Fee recipient");
    
    accessControls = _accessControls;
    cardNFT = _cardNFT;
    platformFeeRecipient = _platformFeeRecipient;
    keyHash = 0xcaf3c3727e033261d383b315559476f48034c13b18f8cafed4d871abe5049186;
    rngFee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK
  }

  /**
    @notice create one NFT
    @param _limit min or maximum number of card
    @param _kind limit kind with lower or higher
    @param _price price of NFT mint
    @param _amount amount of NFTs to mint
    @param _data additional data to leave
   */
  function create(uint256 _limit, bool _kind, uint256 _price, uint256 _amount, bytes memory _data) external payable nonReentrant whenNotPaused {
    require(_msgSender().isContract() == false, "Factory.create: No contracts are permitted");
    require(_msgSender() != address(0), "Factory.create: sender address is ZERO");
    uint256 buyPrice = msg.value;
    require(buyPrice >= _price, "Factory.create: payment should be same to original price");

    // (bool platformTransferSuccess,) = platformFeeRecipient.call{value : buyPrice}("");
    // require(platformTransferSuccess, "Factory.mintPayment: Failed to send platform fee");

    address creator = _msgSender();
    if(_amount > 1) {
      uint256[] memory _ids = cardNFT.batchMint(creator, _amount, _data);
      require(_amount == _ids.length, "Factory.create: should batch mint same amount of nfts");
      for(uint256 i=0; i<_ids.length; i++) {
        getRandomNumber(_ids[i], _limit, _kind);
      }
    } else {
      uint256 id = cardNFT.mint(creator, _data);
      getRandomNumber(id, _limit, _kind);
    }
  }

  /**
    @notice generate actual NFT info
    @param _requestId request id for chainlink rng
    @param _randomness random number which return from chainlink org
   */
  function generateNFTInfo(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness) private {
    RequestNFTConfig storage config = requestIds[_requestId];
    uint256 total = getTotalQtyToNumber(config.limit);
    bool _kind = config.kind;
    uint256 rngResult = 0;
    if(_kind) {
      rngResult = _randomness * (200000 - total) + total;
    } else {
      rngResult = _randomness * total;
    }
    uint256 cardInfoId = getNearestQtyCard(rngResult);
    NFTInfo storage nft = nfts[config.id];
    uint256 edition = _getNextEditionID();
    _incrementEditionId();
    nft.edition = edition;
    nft.cardInfoId = cardInfoId;
    CardInfo storage cardInfo = deckInfo[cardInfoId];

    emit NFTCreated(config.id, cardInfo.num, cardInfo.kind, edition);
  }

  /** 
    * Requests randomness 
    */
  function getRandomNumber(uint256 _id, uint256 _limit, bool _kind) private {
    require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= rngFee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
    bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, rngFee);
    RequestNFTConfig storage config = requestIds[requestId];
    config.id = _id;
    config.kind = _kind;
    config.limit = _limit;
  }

  /**
    * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
    */
  function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
    emit RandomReturned(requestId, randomness);
    generateNFTInfo(requestId, randomness);
  }

  ......
}
```

I tried this one on BSC testnet but no **RandomReturned** event log and also no updates with generateNFTInfo function.
Also I am not sure how to test unit test on my local without installing chainlink-node on my local.
Can anybody help me on this one?

Comment: Hi @all-in-one, if you update your contract to use Ethereum Kovan does it work? ie use the Kovan settings from here docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts , then deploy to Kovan, fund with LINK and execute. The answer to this will tell us if its your code, or if it's the BSC testnet network.

If it doesn't work on Kovan as well, can you update your fulfillRandomness function to just store the random number in the contract instead of calling the generateNFTInfo function, then try again? This will tell us if it's an issue with the VRF Node or your function that runs

Answer (score -1):

I thought I ran into the same issue, however, I found that it can take over 2 minutes to generate a random number depending on network congestion. I am testing in the Rinkeby network.